# Perl Net::Telnet Module

Tags: perl, telnet, prompt

I am trying to write a perl module that uses the Net::Telnet code, but the problem is the prompt. I am writing the application for other user and not sure of what the prompt pattern they might have. Is there a way I can get the prompt at run time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Telnet on remote side spawns a new shell-session, (you are right) it depends on user's profile how the prompt will look like. It is common for shells to read the prompt format from `PS1` variable. So you need to execute something like:

```
echo $PS1
\u@\h:\w>
```

to read how the prompt looks like.

Answer (score 1):

The default value for prompt should be pretty good in almost all circumstances.

It looks for any string that ends with either a `#` or a `$` or a `%` followed by a space. The `#` is used by root, the `%` is used by C Style shells, and the `$` is used by Bourne style shells like BASH and Kornshell.

If you're using Telnet, it's very likely you're logging into an account where the default prompt will work.

I prefer to use [Net::SSH::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~turnstep/Net-SSH-Perl-1.34/lib/Net/SSH/Perl.pm) and not worry about user prompts. `Net::SSH::Perl` is more secure and I can transfer files, or execute commands with it.

Comment: nowadays, [Net::SSH2](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::SSH2) or [Net::OpenSSH](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::OpenSSH) are probably better choices than `Net::SSH::Perl`

Comment: The board doesnt support ssh :(